# How do I cleanup Postgres WAL?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

What is the correct way to cleanup WAL postgres? I have a database with more than 100 GB and it haves around 600 GB in pg_wal. Also I have 2 logical replications set up.

Master and Slaves - Postgres 10.

Master and Slaves have commented `wal_keep_segments` and `max_wal_size`.

`pg_archivecleanup` did not work with `%r` option, then I got the archive name by searching in `pg_controldata` latest checkpoint's REDO WAL file and deleted the logs, but then one replica stopped with the error

> could not receive data from WAL stream: FATAL: requested WAL segment xxx has already been removed

To solve this I deleted and recreated the replica.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`pg_wal` cleans itself up. You should almost never touch `pg_wal` by hand. If it is not cleaning itself up, you need to figure out why and fix the underlying issue.

One possible reason is that you have a replication slot that is holding it back.  Either a replica is using a slot and is unable to keep up, or you have a slot that has no replica attached, for example, you destroyed the replica but didn't drop the slot it used to occupy.  You can see what slots you have by querying [`pg_replication_slots`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-replication-slots.html), and if necessary drop one with [`pg_drop_replication_slot`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-REPLICATION), both run on the master.  You would look for the slot with the oldest non-NULL value of `restart_lsn`.

Another reason could be that you have `archive_mode` turned on, but your `archive_command` is constantly failing or can't keep up.  You will see warnings about this in your server log file if it is failing.

`pg_archivecleanup` is used to clean up a WAL *archive*.  `pg_wal` is not the archive, it contains the *live* WAL files. You are lucky you didn't destroy your database by monkeying around in there.

Comment: Thanks for answering, unfortunately I don't have any replication slot in master that is not being used, and all is in sync, also archive mode is off.

Comment: Can you turn log_checkpoints on, reload the server, then run a few checkpoints and see what it logs?  Can you double check that wal_keep_segments and archive_mode are actually off by using "SHOW" on a runninger server?

Comment: The last days I was monitoring the disk usage and it seems that after I recreated the replica the space was normalized.